# ArrayList of object of different (Inherited) classes with a generic parameter in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

*Note : For the sake of simplicity, I removed methods like init and specific functions.*

I have an abstract class called Role.

```
abstract class Role {}
```

From that class I have inherited many classes like Knight, Sorcerer ... etc.

```
class Knight(context: Context) : Role() {}
class Srocerer(context: Context) : Role() {}
```

And Then I have created another abstract Class having a generic parameter **R : Role**

```
abstract class Turn<R : Role> {}
```

*Not every role (player) can play a turn*

And as you may expect I also inherited some classes like KngithTurn, SorcererTurn ... etc.

```
class KnightTurn(role : Knight) : Turn<Knight>() {}
class SorcererTurn(role : Sorcerer) : Turn<Sorcerer>() {}
```

The problem is when I create an arrayList of Turn, and try to add an object of type KnightTurn or SorcererTurn, the IDE says that there is a type mismatch despite the fact that they are inherited from class Turn.

```
var list = ArrayList<Turn<Role>>()
val knight = KnightTurn(Knight(baseContext))
list.add(knight) 

// Type mismatch
// Required:Turn<Role>
// Found:KnightTurn
```

In java, I just solve the problem like this:

```
ArrayList<Turn<Role?>>
```

How can I do it in Kotlin, or is there any other solution?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The type `ArrayList<Turn<Role?>>` is not valid Java syntax. Additionally, you might want to have a  look into the following question: [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Comment: How about `ArrayList<Turn<*>>`?

Comment: try `list.add(knight as Turn<Role>)`

Comment: @Stachu this can lead to ClassCastException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring your list like this indicates that only `Turn`s with a type parameter of exactly `Role` can be added to the list.

> ```
> var list = ArrayList<Turn<Role>>()
> ```

You want to be able to add `Turn`s with anything that derives from `Role`, if I understand correctly. This means you should use the `out` keyword:

```
var list = ArrayList<Turn<out Role>>()
```

After I make that change, this code compiles without error:

```
val knight = KnightTurn(Knight())
list.add(knight)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those that didn't see Stachu's response to OP:

The ["unsafe" cast operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator) is used in cases like this.

Code

```
list.add(knight as Turn<Role>)
```